# tns run android --emulator Fails when executed for the first time

Tags: android, npm, angular, nativescript

I am following the tutorial on http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1

I have cloned the sample project and added android platform successfully.
i have configured my AVD and its running.

But when i run `tns run android --emulator` for the first time i get the error as
`Unable to install dependencies. Make sure your package.json is valid and all dependencies are correct. Error is: 400 Bad Request`

Any pointers on this issue ?

Comment: try genymotion , u will like it more

Comment: can you add your package.json to your question?

Comment: Looks like the problem was in my package.json file.
Initially i had done `git checkout angular-start`

This command replaced my `package.json` with initial file which causes some problem.

Now i replaced my package.json file with https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/master/package.json
and it is working now. Thanks @NoumanShah